# Question about translating English to first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Which of the following are possible (semantically and syntactically correct) first-order-logic translation of "Salma loves any class which is harder than every Algorithms class".

Is the following translation correct ? and Why ?

$\forall x \forall y[[Class(x) \land AlClass(y) \land Harder(x,y)] \to Loves(Salma,x)]$

My prof considered it as a wrong translation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote means: For any $x$ and any $y$, if $x$ is a Class
and $y$ is an Algorithm Class and $x$ is harder than $y$, then Salma
loves $x$. That means, any $y$ will do, as long as it is Algorithm
Class and $x$ is harder than it. Then, even if some $z$ is an Algorithm
Class, but $x$ is not harder than $z$, Salma still loves $x$.

In fact, using the properties of quantifiers, you can transform your
proposition into the following:
$$\forall x\left[Class(x)\wedge\exists y\left[AlClass(y)\wedge Harder(x,y)\right]\rightarrow Loves(Salma,x)\right]\tag{1}$$
That means: for every $x$, if $x$ is a Class and there is a $y$,
such that it is an Algorithm Class and $x$ is harder than it, then
Salma loves $x$. To see that the above is equivalent to what you
wrote, consider the following properties:

$$\forall y\left[P(y)\rightarrow Q\right]\leftrightarrow\left[\exists yP(y)\rightarrow Q\right]$$
$$\exists y\left[Q\wedge P(y)\right]\leftrightarrow\left[Q\wedge\exists yP(y)\right]$$

where $Q$ is any proposition with no free occurrence of "$y$".
Applying these to your formula, together with the fact that $\wedge$
is associative, gives (1). This is not what the exercise is asking for. Salma should love a Class
$x$, if $x$ is harder than every Algorithm Class.

Comment: my argument is that two universal quantifiers are equivalent to a pure representation of  conjunctions whenever the implication fails the overall expression will throw false as a truth value but if the implication does not fail for every possible assignment therefore the expression will throw true, i am looking to the final result after finishing the looping if we look at it as a program, i know that may give me that salma loves class x as it is harder than y1 but when we reach y2 that will make the overall expression false

Answer (score 1):

> Salma loves any class which is harder than every Algorithms class

Here we want two conditions for the class, say $a$ that Salma loves:
\begin{align}
1.&~\text{$a$ is a class.}\\
&~Class(a)\\
2.&~\text{$a$ is harder than every Algorithms class.}\\
&~\forall y(AlClass(y) \to Harder(a,y))
\end{align}
So the correct translation would be
$$\forall x[[Class(x) \land\forall y(AlClass(y) \to Harder(x,y))]\to Loves(Salma,x)]$$

---

Now let's have a look on your translation
\begin{align}
&\forall x \forall y[[Class(x) \land AlClass(y) \land Harder(x,y)] \to Loves(Salma,x)]\\
\equiv&\forall x[[Class(x) \land\exists y(AlClass(y) \land Harder(x,y))] \to Loves(Salma,x)]
\end{align}
the conditions here are
\begin{align}
1.&~\text{$a$ is a class}\\
&~Class(a)\\
\hat2.&~\text{$a$ harder than some Algorithms class $y$}\\
&~\exists y(AlClass(y)\land Harder(a,y))
\end{align}

---

That conditions $2.$ and $\hat2.$ are not equivalent i.e.
$$\forall y(AlClass(y) \to Harder(a,y))\not\equiv\exists y(AlClass(y)\land Harder(a,y))$$
do you see their difference?